# why do i get this error: cannot find symbol temp after while(temp

Tags: java

```java
Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);    
int x=in.nextInt();    
Queue<Integer> a=new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
Queue<Integer> b=new ArrayDeque<Integer>();

for(int a_i=0; a_i < n; a_i++){
    a.offer(in.nextInt());
}
for(int b_i=0; b_i < m; b_i++){
    b.offer(in.nextInt());
}  

int temp=0,ans=0;
while(temp<x && !a.empty() && !b.empty()){ 
    temp+=a.peek()<b.peek()?a.poll():b.poll();
    ans++;             
}
```

when i run this 
    Solution.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
            while(temp

Comment: What is `x` that temp is being compared against in the while loop?

Comment: Post the complete code so that we can help. where is `x` declared?

Comment: I declared 'x' as int at the top of my code. It seems the  problem rose because of the empty() method I used for the Queue. After I changed it to isEmpty()  my code worked. Btw thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `x` is not declared anywhere that I can see. I would imagine this is your problem. You need to declare `x` with a data type and give it an initial value before you compare against it.